# Accessing remote Glassfish Web Administrator GUI on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: jsf, ubuntu, glassfish

I've just setup Glassfish 4.1 on my Ubuntu 14.04 VPS and everything went perfect, I even have it connected with my local Netbeans and have no issue deploying applications to it.

The only problem is i can't seem to get http(s)://my-host:4848 working, it would open the Admin GUI and stuck saying "`Status: The Admin Console is starting. Please wait`."

I checked the log on Firefox and Chrome, on both of them i'm seeing `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` and it's coming from testifbackendisready.html line 135 which has xmlhttp.send() command.

I have tried `change-master-password`, `change-admin-password`, `enable-secure-admin` -> restart the server -> try to go to admin page and still nothing, same error. 
I turned off my firewall on my server, by emptying the iptable and still getting the same error. 
I checked the server.log and found nothing suspicious, to give you an idea i copy paste several lines from my server.log right after trying to access admin page

```
[2015-05-04T20:54:50.254-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [NCLS-JMX-00020]       [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=62 _ThreadName=Thread-15]     [timeMillis: 14307872All SSL cipher suites disabled for network-listener(s).  Using SSL implementation specific defaults]]$

[2015-05-04T20:54:50.381-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-JMX-00025] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=62 _ThreadName=Thread-15] [timeMillis: 14307872903 SSLServerSocket /0.0.0.0:8686 and [SSL: ServerSocket[addr=/0.0.0.0,localport=8686]] created]]$

[2015-05-04T20:54:53.137-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-JMX-00005] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=62 _ThreadName=Thread-15] [timeMillis: 14307872931 JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://rey-vps:8686/jndi/rmi://rey-vps:8686/jmxrmi]]$

[2015-05-04T20:55:24.922-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=95 _ThreadName=Thread-20] [timeMillis: 14307 visiting unvisited references]]$

[2015-05-04T20:55:25.501-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=95 _ThreadName=Thread-20] [timeMillis: 14307 visiting unvisited references]]$

[2015-05-04T20:55:25.510-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=95 _ThreadName=Thread-20] [timeMillis: 14307 visiting unvisited references]]$

[2015-05-04T20:55:25.512-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=95 _ThreadName=Thread-20] [timeMillis: 14307 visiting unvisited references]]$

[2015-05-04T20:55:27.582-0400] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [jsf.config.listener.version][javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] [tid: _ThreadID=95 _ThreadName=Initializing Mojarra 2.2.7 ( 20140610-1547 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.7@13362) for context '']]$
```

Let me know if any of those lines could be the culprit or i might have missed something.

Note: I changed /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle(my jdk)/jre/security/server.policy to allow localhost:1527 to listen, my intention is so that derby can be run from the server in case I want to migrate my DB from my local machine to the server

One last question that still bothers me, as I'm new with setting up any kind of Web/App Server in a remote machine.

When I start the domain should I use the --host parameter and specify my IP(I don't have domain name so i'm just using my IP address to access my Server either 80 or 22 with Putty) I tried both and they did not make any difference.

I'm sorry if i missed some logs that might be important, but I can definitely provides everything that would help fixing this problem. I'm still trying to figure out a lot of things with *NIX and the server so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you

Ray Renaldi

Comment: Figured it out. Lesson learned, never put things if you don't know what it's for, Xms 4096m when my Server's RAM is 1024 is the cause.